# Does path of electron exist from one orbital to another?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In atom, electron changes orbital by absorbing and releasing energy.
Electrons can suddenly jump when energy is high but my question is: does actual path exist or not?
And perhaps electron disappears from its orbit and some time later appears other orbit. Is it possible?

According to Heisenberg uncertainty principle, we can't find exactly position of an electron. Then can I tell that electron disappears for some time?
If no, in which path does the electron cover the smallest distance from one orbital to another?

Comment: Are you picturing bound electrons as point like objects in orbit around the nucleus that take a 'transfer orbit' to a different orbital?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri , I'm picturing electron moves in principle quantum number and change it's by absorbing and releasing energy.

Comment: Priyanshu, I'm not sure I follow. Perhaps you could clarify what you're thinking about by *"does actual path exists or not?"*. I can't begin to think about how to answer unless I'm clear on how you're thinking about this.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri ,I mean when electron change principle quantum number then electron have some specific path or not? Electron have some Trajectory or else electron disappear for sometime when change principle quantum number and appear again in other orbit.

Comment: *"Electron have some Trajectory"* - this is the idea that you must reexamine. Only in the [Bohmian interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) do electrons have definite trajectories, but to accept that, one must accept that an electron in a stationary state, e.g., the ground state of hydrogen, is *literally stationary*. If I find the time, I'll flesh this comment out into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An electron orbital is a 3D resonant standing wave pattern.  With an exchange of energy, the wave shifts to another resonant pattern. The amplitude of the wave at any given point determines the probability that the electron will interact with something else at that point. That's all that you can say about the location or path of the electron.

Comment: And the standing waves are stationary states but the superpositions during the shift have charge distributions that oscillate with the difference frequency.